# Unable to replicate this ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrough

I am unable to replicate an example from the `ggrough` library (https://xvrdm.github.io/ggrough/articles/Customize%20chart.html). In particular, I am trying to replicate the following plot (minus the font aspects):

[image]

The code is from the same link above under the "Kindergarten" header.

I am using the following code:

```
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(gcookbook)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrough)
ggplot(uspopage, aes(x=Year, y=Thousands, fill=AgeGroup)) + 
    geom_area(alpha=0.8) +
    scale_fill_ipsum() +
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_comma() -> p 

options <- list(GeomArea=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                              angle_noise=0.5,
                              gap_noise=0.2,
                              gap=1.5,
                              fill_weight=1))
get_rough_chart(p, options)
```

However, I am unable to replicate the above. Here is what I get:

[image]

Again, I am not worried about the fonts, but do want to get the shaded geom_area to work. It currently doesn't render at all. For reference, here is what the `p` object yields (i.e., the plot before it goes through the `ggrough` processing):

[image]

Also note that I am able to replicate the "Blueprint" example, which uses `geom_col`. So it appears that something is going wrong with `ggrough` processing the `geom_area`, but not sure.

Comment: package ‘ggrough’ is not available (for R version 4.0.1)
 - seems to be not on CRAN

Comment: ah from github only

Comment: Tried it also did not work out. From the package description I am assuming, it just doesn't work in the current Github version - ggrough is a work in progress and still has big bugs. Contributions are welcome!"

Comment: Good point - see this page for installation instructions: https://github.com/xvrdm/ggrough

Comment: I'm getting the same bogus chart you are.  Just a thought, this is tidyverse-dependent and hasn't been updated in 2 years, I would expect some pretty significant breakage ...

Comment: @BenBolker Right...I was hoping that wouldn't be the answer, but looks like it likely is. It would be really nice to be able to make these sketchy-style graphs directly in R without having to learn Semiotic/Javascript (https://semiotic.nteract.io/guides/sketchy-painty-patterns).

Comment: Did another check (postet it as an answer for you, because it being too long). But I pretty much came to the same conclusion as you - that it is a problem with geom_area. Even took a quick look at the package source, but at first glance found no quick fix for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ggrough package doesn't work well with the current version of ggplot2 for `geom_area`, because it looks for the target area in xml nodes bearing the name "polyline". In older versions of ggplot2, this probably worked fine, because each area was enclosed by a polyline. In more recent versions, however, this is no longer the case (see [breaking changes under 3.3.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/news/news.html)).

See if the following works for you:

1. Define a version of the `parse_*` function that look for "polygon", rather than "polyline".

```
parse_polygons <- function (svg) {
  shape <- "polygon" # was "polyline" in ggrough:::parse_areas
  keys <- NULL
  ggrough:::parse_shape(svg, shape, keys) %>% {
    purrr::map(., 
               ~purrr::list_modify(.x, 
                                   points = stringr::str_squish(.x$points) %>% 
                                     {stringr::str_glue("M{.}Z")}, 
                                   shape = "path"))
  }
}
```

2. Change the corresponding un-exported function in ggrough to use the newly defined `parse_polygons` for GeomArea layers.

In addition, I've added in GeomRibbon (which appeared to be missing from the original but is really a more general case of GeomArea) & moved GeomViolin over from `parse_areas` to `parse_polygons`, because it faces the same issue.

(Note: GeomSmooth will probably break too, but I think its parse function will take a bit more tweaking, compared to GeomRibbon / GeomViolin, & I'm not seeing a use case for it...)

```
trace(ggrough:::parse_rough, edit = TRUE)

# paste the following function into the pop-up window
function (svg, geom) {
  rough_els <- list()
  if (geom %in% c("GeomCol", "GeomBar", "GeomTile", "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_rects(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomSmooth", "Background")) {   # removed GeomArea / GeomViolin from here
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_areas(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomArea", "GeomRibbon", "GeomViolin")) {  # new condition here
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_polygons(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomPoint", "GeomJitter", "GeomDotPlot", "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_circles(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomLine", "GeomSmooth", "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_lines(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_texts(svg))
  }
  purrr::map(rough_els, ~purrr::list_modify(.x, geom = geom))
}
```

Test:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrough)

uspopage <- gcookbook::uspopage
p <- ggplot(uspopage, aes(x=Year, y=Thousands, fill=AgeGroup)) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.8) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)); p
options <- list(GeomArea=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                              angle_noise=0.5,
                              gap_noise=0.2,
                              gap=1.5,
                              fill_weight=1))
get_rough_chart(p, options)
```

[image: geom_area plot]

Additional test for `geom_ribbon`:

```
# using example from geom_ribbon help page
pp <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level - 1, ymax = level + 1), 
              fill = "grey70")
options <- list(GeomRibbon=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                                angle_noise=0.5,
                                gap_noise=0.2,
                                gap=1.5,
                                fill_weight=1))
get_rough_chart(pp, options)
```

[image: geom_ribbon plot]

Session info:

```
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Singapore.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Singapore.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Singapore.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Singapore.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gdtools_0.2.2 dplyr_1.0.0   ggrough_0.1.0 ggplot2_3.3.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5        cpp11_0.2.1       pillar_1.4.6      compiler_4.0.1   
 [5] plyr_1.8.6        Rmisc_1.5         forcats_0.5.0     tools_4.0.1      
 [9] boot_1.3-25       digest_0.6.25     jsonlite_1.7.1    lifecycle_0.2.0  
[13] tibble_3.0.3      gtable_0.3.0      lattice_0.20-41   pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[17] rlang_0.4.7       rstudioapi_0.11   yaml_2.2.1        xml2_1.3.2       
[21] withr_2.2.0       stringr_1.4.0     htmlwidgets_1.5.1 systemfonts_0.3.1
[25] generics_0.0.2    vctrs_0.3.4       grid_4.0.1        tidyselect_1.1.0 
[29] data.table_1.12.8 svglite_1.2.3.2   glue_1.4.2        R6_2.4.1         
[33] gcookbook_2.0     tidyr_1.1.0       reshape2_1.4.4    purrr_0.3.4      
[37] farver_2.0.3      magrittr_1.5      htmltools_0.5.0   scales_1.1.1     
[41] ellipsis_0.3.1    fortunes_1.5-4    colorspace_1.4-1  labeling_0.3     
[45] stringi_1.5.3     munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for figuring this out—it works great now!

Answer (score 5):

I am writing this as an answer, because it would be too long for the comments.

I also tried the `ggrough`  package for you:

The following example from their github readme works perfectly:

```
library(ggplot2)
count(mtcars, carb) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carb, n)) +
  geom_col() + 
  labs(title="Number of cars by carburator count") + 
  theme_grey(base_size = 16) -> p 
p

library(ggrough)
options <- list(
  Background=list(roughness=8),
  GeomCol=list(fill_style="zigzag", angle_noise=0.5, fill_weight=2))
get_rough_chart(p, options)
```

[image]

Yet, when I am trying your example:

```
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(gcookbook)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrough)
ggplot(uspopage, aes(x=Year, y=Thousands, fill=AgeGroup)) + 
    geom_area(alpha=0.8) +
    scale_fill_ipsum() +
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_comma() -> p 
p
```

That is alright till here, this would give the following image:

[image]

Now we would need to add the ggrough part.

```
options <- list(GeomArea=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                              angle_noise=0.5,
                              gap_noise=0.2,
                              gap=1.5,
                              fill_weight=1))
get_rough_chart(p, options)
```

I get pretty much the same result  as you:

[image]

I came to the same conclusion as you:

> So it appears that something is going wrong with ggrough processing the geom_area

Could even use all the same settings for the ggrough part successfully (with the only difference being `GeomCol`) for the above number of cars example.

As the Github page says:

> ggrough is a work in progress and still has big bugs. Contributions are welcome!"

They made their last Git commit 2 years ago.

Now, since the plot you wanted to create is from their own examples, I am pretty sure it once worked. (I mean why would they upload fake plots)

So if you are really desperate you could try:

- Install a ggplot2 version (and other required packages) from 2 years ago
- Install an older commit version from the `ggrough` package. Maybe they made a commit that broke the once working example.

Or you try to fix their package ;)