# How to shade shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrough

Is it possible to use `ggrough` (https://xvrdm.github.io/ggrough/index.html) to shade shapes created by `geom_sf` (preferred) or potentially `geom_polygon`? See this question for a prior question that gives the look of the plot I have in mind and the accompanying answer by Z.Lin that modifies the package to make it compatible with the current version of `ggplot2`: [Unable to replicate this ggplot2 plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759571/unable-to-replicate-this-ggplot2-plot?noredirect=1#comment112795312_63759571).

Here is a MWE of a map created using `geom_sf` that I would like to shade (each individual county) using `ggrough`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrough)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tidycensus)
library(viridis)
#install.packages("devtools") # if you have not installed "devtools" package
#devtools::install_github("xvrdm/ggrough")
library(hrbrthemes)

#get nevada shapefile
counties <- get_acs(
    geography = "county", year = 2018, geometry = TRUE,
    variables = "B19013_001", keep_geo_vars=TRUE
) %>% filter(STATEFP=="32")
counties$GEOID <- as.integer(counties$GEOID)
#############

a <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = counties, aes(fill = estimate)) + 
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete=FALSE, name="", guide=FALSE) +  
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.15, .15)) +
    theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.8, vjust=-10, size=30)) +  
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) +
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank())+
    theme(legend.position = c(0.25, .15), legend.key.size = unit(2,"line"),
          legend.title=element_text(size=16), 
          legend.text=element_text(size=14), 
          legend.direction = "vertical", 
          legend.box = "horizontal") +
    labs(caption = "")
a
```

This produces the following:

[image]

How can I shade the counties of this map using `ggrough` or is this not possible? Note that I think that `ggrough` can handle `geom_col, geom_bar, geom_tile, geom_geom_area, geom_ribbon, geom_violin, geom_point, geom_jitter, geom_dotplot, geom_line, and geom_smooth`, but I am not sure about `geom_sf` or `geom_polygon`; if not, would it be easy to add them in?

***Update
Here is another example, taken from https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html:

```
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
b <- ggplot(nc) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))
b
```

This produces:

[image]

***End update

(Here is an example, created with `ggrough`, of how I want the shading of the counties to look:
[image]
)

Here is a failed attempt (again relying on code from Z.Lin's answer here: [Unable to replicate this ggplot2 plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759571/unable-to-replicate-this-ggplot2-plot?noredirect=1#comment112795312_63759571)):

```
parse_polygons <- function (svg) {
    shape <- "polygon" # was "polyline" in ggrough:::parse_areas
    keys <- NULL
    ggrough:::parse_shape(svg, shape, keys) %>% {
        purrr::map(., 
                   ~purrr::list_modify(.x, 
                                    points = stringr::str_squish(.x$points) %>% 
                                        {stringr::str_glue("M{.}Z")}, 
                                    shape = "path"))
    }
}

trace(ggrough:::parse_rough, edit = TRUE)

# paste the following function into the pop-up window
function (svg, geom) {
    rough_els <- list()
    if (geom %in% c("GeomCol", "GeomBar", "GeomTile", "Background")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_rects(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("GeomSmooth", "Background")) {   # removed GeomArea / GeomViolin from here
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_areas(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("GeomArea", "GeomRibbon", "GeomViolin")) {  # new condition here
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_polygons(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("GeomPoint", "GeomJitter", "GeomDotPlot", "Background")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_circles(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("GeomLine", "GeomSmooth", "Background")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_lines(svg))
    }
    if (geom %in% c("Background")) {
        rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_texts(svg))
    }
    purrr::map(rough_els, ~purrr::list_modify(.x, geom = geom))
}

options <- list(GeomSf=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                              angle_noise=0.5,
                              gap_noise=0.2,
                              gap=1.5,
                              fill_weight=1))
get_rough_chart(a, options)
```

This produces the error message:

```
Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

***Update

Or with the second example:

```
options <- list(GeomSf=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                          angle_noise=0.5,
                          gap_noise=0.2,
                          gap=1.5,
                          fill_weight=1))
get_rough_chart(b, options)
```

Same error.

***End update.

Note also that it is possible to create maps using `geom_polygon`, so that is of interest as well, though `geom_sf` is preferred.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? The Census API requires an API key. I've tried `ggrough` with the first example of https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html which actually doesn't throw an error but returns an empty plot.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely do this. Thanks for letting me know about the Census API problem - I didn't consider that.

Comment: I just updated the question with the second example. I still get the same error. Interesting that yours didn't and made the plot, albeit empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrough)
```

Replace `parse_rough` using `trace`

```
trace(ggrough:::parse_rough, edit=TRUE)
```

In the popup window, paste this so that `parse_rough` will use `parse_sf` for `GeomSf`.

```
function (svg, geom) 
{
  rough_els <- list()
  if (geom %in% c("GeomCol", "GeomBar", "GeomTile", 
                  "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_rects(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomArea", "GeomViolin", "GeomSmooth", 
                  "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_areas(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomPoint", "GeomJitter", "GeomDotPlot", 
                  "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_circles(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomLine", "GeomSmooth", "Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_lines(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("Background")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_texts(svg))
  }
  if (geom %in% c("GeomSf")) {
    rough_els <- append(rough_els, parse_sf(svg))
  }
  purrr::map(rough_els, ~purrr::list_modify(.x, geom = geom))
}
```

Create the function `parse_sf`.

```
parse_sf <- function (svg) {
  shape <- "path"
  keys <- NULL
  ggrough:::parse_shape(svg, shape, keys) %>% {
    purrr::map(., 
               ~purrr::list_modify(.x, 
                                   points = .x$d, 
                                   shape = "path"
               ))
  }
}
```

Create the desired plot

```
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
b <- ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))
b


options <- list(GeomSf=list(fill_style="hachure", 
                            angle_noise=0.5,
                            gap_noise=0.2,
                            gap=1.5,
                            fill_weight=1))
get_rough_chart(b, options)
```

[image]